# Unexpected behavior with overloaded methods

Tags: groovy

I'm a bit confused about groovys method overloading behavior: Given the class
and tests below, I am pretty okay with `testAStringNull` and `testBStringNull`
throwing ambiguous method call exceptions, but why is that not the case for
`testANull` and `testBNull` then?

And, much more importantly: why does `testBNull(null)`
call `String foo(A arg)`? I guess the object doesn't know about the type of the variable it's bound to, but why is that call not ambiguous to groovy while the others are?

(I hope I explained well enough, my head hurts from generating this minimal
example.)

```
class Foo {
    static class A {}
    static class B {}

    String foo(A arg) { return 'a' }

    String foo(String s, A a) { return 'a' }

    String foo(B arg) { return 'b' }

    String foo(String s, B b) { return 'b' }
}
```

Tests:

```
import org.junit.Test
import Foo.A
import Foo.B

class FooTest {
    Foo foo = new Foo()

    @Test
    void testA() {
        A a = new A()
        assert foo.foo(a) == 'a'
    }

    @Test
    void testAString() {
        A a = new A()
        assert foo.foo('foo', a) == 'a'
    }

    @Test()
    void testANull() {
        A a = null
        assert foo.foo(a) == 'a'
    }

    @Test
    void testAStringNull() {
        A a = null
        assert foo.foo('foo', a) == 'a'
    }

    @Test
    void testB() {
        B b = new B()
        assert foo.foo(b) == 'b'
    }

    @Test
    void testBString() {
        B b = new B()
        assert foo.foo('foo', b) == 'b'
    }

    @Test
    void testBNull() {
        B b = null
        assert foo.foo(b) == 'b'
    }

    @Test
    void testBStringNull() {
        B b = null
        assert foo.foo('foo', b) == 'b'
    }

}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's a (somewhat little-known) oddity of Groovy's multi-dispatch mechanism, which as attempting to invoke the "most appropriate" method, in combination with the fact that the provided static type (in your case A or B) is not used as part of the dispatch mechanism. When you declare A a = null, what you get is not a null reference of type A, but a reference to NullObject.

Ultimately, to safely handle possibly null parameters to overloaded methods, the caller must cast the argument, as in

```
A a = null
assert foo.foo('foo', a as A) == 'a'
```

This discussion on ["Groovy Isn't A Superset of Java"](https://schneide.wordpress.com/2010/12/27/groovy-isnt-a-superset-of-java) may shed some light on the issue.

Comment: Good answer. Hey, isn't there a stuff regarding a "path from the nearest class" related to this?

Comment: And how do you write a method which excepts null without using "a as A"? I don't want to get an exception of ambiguous methods.

Comment: Does not work for me, groovy 3.0.9 in gradle

Comment: @AlexPanchenko -ok, so 10 years later,  I just tried this again in Groovy 3.0.9, and it works. So it probably has something to do with Gradle...

Comment: @AlexPanchenko: it works in Gradle 7.5 as well