# How to stub overloaded method in Mockito using Groovy?

Tags: java, groovy, mockito

Groovy appears to be messing up my stubbing. The following test passes:

**MockitoStubTest2.java:**

```
public class MockitoStubTest2 {
  @Test
  public void testStubbing() {
    MyInterface myInterface = mock(MyInterface.class);
    when(myInterface.someMethod(isA(MyClass.class))).thenReturn("foobar");
    assertEquals("foobar", myInterface.someMethod(new MyClass()));
  }

  private interface MyInterface {
    String someMethod(MyClass arg);
    String someMethod(String arg);
  }

  private static class MyClass {}
}
```

However, this one fails with `groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Ambiguous method overloading for method ...#someMethod`:

**MockitoStubTest3.groovy:**

```
public class MockitoStubTest3 {
  @Test
  public void testStubbing() {
    MyInterface myInterface = mock(MyInterface.class);
    when(myInterface.someMethod(isA(MyClass.class))).thenReturn("foobar");
    assertEquals("foobar", myInterface.someMethod(new MyClass()));
  }

  private interface MyInterface {
    String someMethod(MyClass arg);
    String someMethod(String arg);
  }

  private static class MyClass {}
}
```

The only difference is that one is run with Java and the other with Groovy.

How can I make it so Mockito will successfully stub an overloaded method in Groovy? This is a trivial example but I have an actual use case I need to test.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok I figured it out right after I posted this question... even though I've been fighting with this all day.

The problem is that the Mockito matcher methods return `null` but Groovy for some reason screws up the type-cast. So you need to do the type-cast manually in order for it to find the correct method to stub. The following works:

**MockitoStubTest3.groovy:**

```
public class MockitoStubTest3 {
  @Test
  public void testStubbing() {
    MyInterface myInterface = mock(MyInterface.class);
    when(myInterface.someMethod(isA(MyClass.class) as MyClass)).thenReturn("foobar");
    assertEquals("foobar", myInterface.someMethod(new MyClass()));
  }

  private interface MyInterface {
    String someMethod(MyClass arg);
    String someMethod(String arg);
  }

  private static class MyClass {}
}
```

I got the answer from this similar question: [Mockito any matcher not working for doAnswer with overloaded method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25857019/mockito-any-matcher-not-working-for-doanswer-with-overloaded-method)

Comment: Great! Struggling with this issue also took me the whole day, when both upgrading Mockito and Groovy to the latest major versions. Eventually I discovered this solution. Thanks a lot!