# Groovy 2.x and Mockito not playing nicely together

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, jersey, jax-rs, mockito

I am trying to write some unit tests for some code that uses [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/) to hit a RESTful web service, and am using [Mockito](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/) to mock out some things. Here's my code:

```
@Test
void test() {
    given:
    // WebResource is a Jersey/JAX-RS construct.
    WebResource mockResource = Mockito.mock(WebResource)

    // Address.groovy is a POJO from my project.
    Address mockAddress = Mockito.mock(Address)

    // THE NEXT LINE IS WHAT IS THROWING THE EXCEPTION:
    Mockito.when(mockResource.get(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(mockAddress)

    when:
    <omitted for brevity>

    then:
    <omitted for brevity>
}
```

As you can see, I'm *trying* to coerce Jersey to return my `mockAddress` instance whenever the `WebResource` attempts to do an HTTP GET.

When this runs I get:

```
groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Ambiguous method overloading for method com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$1c2e51fa#get.
Cannot resolve which method to invoke for [null] due to overlapping prototypes between:
[class com.sun.jersey.api.client.GenericType]
[class java.lang.Class]
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.chooseMostSpecificParams(MetaClassImpl.java:3031)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.chooseMethodInternal(MetaClassImpl.java:2983)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.chooseMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:2926)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getMethodWithCachingInternal(MetaClassImpl.java:1203)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.createPojoCallSite(MetaClassImpl.java:3130)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.createPojoSite(CallSiteArray.java:129)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.createCallSite(CallSiteArray.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at com.me.myapp.MyUnitTest.test(MyUnitTest.groovy:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    <large stack trace omitted for brevity>
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Where `MyUnitTest.groovy:19` is the line:

```
Mockito.when(mockResource.get(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(mockAddress)
```

Any ideas as to what is going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[WebResource's `get()` method is overloaded with `get(Class)` and `get(GenericType)`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/1.18/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/WebResource.html#get%28java.lang.Class%29).

That seems to be where is ambiguity is, as described in the message. That being said, it doesn't really seems appropriate to use `Mockito.any()`. I'm not a big Mockito user, so I don't know of the normal use cases for using it. When I try to use it with Java, I'll get a compile error, as `Mockit.any()` will return `Object`, and neither of the overloaded methods accept `Object` as an argument.

That being said, the behavior you are mocking, is that when you call `get` on the `WebResource` it should return an `Address` object, so you'll would want to pass `Address.class` (or `Address` in the case of Groovy might be OK, as you mentioned in your previous post) to the `get` method.

Something that should work (at least when I tested with Java) is something like:

```
WebResource resource = Mockito.mock(WebResource.class);
Address address = Mockito.mock(Address.class);

Mockito.when(resource.get(Address.class)).thenReturn(address);
Mockito.when(address.toString()).thenReturn("Hello World");

Address a = resource.get(Address.class);
System.out.println(a);
```

This should print out `"Hello World"`

Answer (score 4):

This is due to the [multiple dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch) mechanism in Groovy.

Just cast the result of the `any()` call to the type of the overloaded method's parameter you are stubbing.

```
when(mockResource.get(any() as Address)).thenReturn(mockAddress)

// this also works
when(mockResource.get(any(Address) as Address)).thenReturn(mockAddress)
```

Imports:

```
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when
```

More details on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12535814/1454261) answer, [this](https://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/09/groovy-goodness-multimethods-or.html) and [this](https://schneide.blog/2010/12/27/groovy-isnt-a-superset-of-java/) blog posts.

Comment: The provided links are all about runtime type information and how Groovy program execution and code development is affected by it.